# Running jenkins on docker (on Windows)... Proper steps to run pipeline job

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to implement docker with jenkins and am not sure if I am on the right track.

**Given:**
Running jenkins on docker from Windows
Plan on fetching code from github, building the solution, running functional tests, etc on a container somehow

**What I've currently done:**

(1)  Installed Docker on Windows

(2) Successfully launched Jenkins on Docker with the command
    "docker run –name myJenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v ~/Jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/ jenkins/jenkins:lts"
  I believe this step binds the docker volume to my host machine's directory. This allows me to view and access the Jenkins content.

(3) In my host machine's Jenkins directory, I've created a plugin.txt (containing a variety of Jenkins plugins I want installed) and a Dockerfile. The Dockerfile installs the specified plugins in the plugins.txt file.

> ```
> FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
> COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
> RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
> ```
>
> (4) In the windows command prompt, I built the Dockerfile with the command "docker build -t new_jenkins_image ."
>   (5) I stop my current container "myJenkins" and create a new container with the command "docker run –name myJenkins2 -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v ~/Jenkins:/var/jenkins_home/ new_jenkins_image". This loads up Jenkins with the newly installed jenkins plugins.

**What I'm stuck/confused on**

(1) Do I have to create a new container with a new name every time I want to install new jenkins plugins through the Dockerfile? This seems like a manual process as well... There has to be a better way.

(2) I started a basic jenkins pipeline job with the "Pipeline script from SCM" option. I entered in the correct repository URL and credentials but left the "Script Path" blank for now (I do not have a Jenkinsfile yet). When I execute the build, Jenkins did not fetch the code from github.

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty path not permitted.
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.PathFilter.create(PathFilter.java:80)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:205)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:249)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.forPath(TreeWalk.java:281)
>   at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFile$3.invoke(GitSCMFile.java:171)
>   at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFile$3.invoke(GitSCMFile.java:165)
>   at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$3.invoke(GitSCMFileSystem.java:193)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.AbstractGitAPIImpl.withRepository(AbstractGitAPIImpl.java:29)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.withRepository(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
>   at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem.invoke(GitSCMFileSystem.java:189)
>   at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFile.content(GitSCMFile.java:165)
>   at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFile.contentAsString(SCMFile.java:338)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:110)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:67)
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:293)
>   at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
> Finished: FAILURE
> ```
>
> I believe it's because the docker container does not have git installed? The container cannot access the Git or MSBuild from my host machine... Do I have to create a new container here to simply fetch the code?

Can someone explain to me what I'm missing or where I went wrong?

From my understanding, the process goes like this: Create new pipeline job -> select pipeline script from scm -> enter repo URL, credentials, branch to build and Jenkinsfile -> Jenkinsfile will execute instructions to compile, test, and deploy.

Where does the Dockerfile come into play here? Is my thought process on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to create container every time if you change/update the image. but it not required to give a new name each time. Did you stopped and removed previously running container? if not so docker gives errors like same name container cannot start. So stop and remove your previous container. and you will be able to start a new container with an updated image.
2. Yes, you need to install git in the same container to pull the code. it cannot access git on the host machine. But the error you are showing is like validation error. (i mean Jenkins validates input even before trying to pull the code. if you add some fake name it will throw next error like git not found)
3. Your thought is on correct track. Create new pipeline job -> select pipeline script from scm -> enter repo URL, credentials, branch to build and Jenkinsfile -> Jenkinsfile will execute instructions to compile, test, and deploy.

At the end of the question, you mentioned about different Dockerfile, i assume you are talking about Dockerfile in your repository (git). you can run your pipeline in docker agent. This removes to setup everything on jenkins host means you dont need to install dependencies to run your pipeline code on host, for example, if you are trying to execute some nodejs code in pipe, you need to setup nodejs on Jenkins host before you run the pipe, to get rid of this you can run pipe in container where everything is pre-setup. But I don't think you can use this feature if you are running Jenkins itself in docker. you need to setup Jenkins on the host directly in that case.